# ADODB Stream Object SaveToFile not working

Tags: asp-classic, stream, adodb

The following classic ASP code does not work - it returns an HTTP status 500 (internal server error):

```html
<%
    Dim sFile, oStream
    sFile = Request.QueryString("File")
    Set oStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Type = 1 ' //adTypeBinary '
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Write Request.BinaryRead(Request.TotalBytes)
    oStream.SaveToFile sFile, 2 ' //adSaveCreateOverWrite '
    oStream.Close
    Set oStream = Nothing
    Response.Write sFile
%>
```

If I comment out the **oStream.SaveToFile** line, it works: HTTP status 200 and returns the file name (C:\testImage.jpg in this case), but obviously the file does not actually get written.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is what worked:

```html
Const maxRead = 200000

Dim sFile, oRead, oWrite, sBuff, iBytes

on error resume next

iBytes = maxRead
sData = Request.BinaryRead(iBytes)
sData = midb(sData, 1, lenb(sData))

Do Until iBytes < 1
  sBuff = Request.BinaryRead(iBytes)

  If iBytes > 0 then
    sData = sData & midb(sBuff, 1, lenb(sBuff))
  End If

Loop
 
on error goto 0

Set oRead = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
oRead.Type = 2 ' adTypeTest
oRead.Open
oRead.WriteText(sData)
 
Set oWrite = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
oWrite.Type = 1 '  adTypeBinary
oWrite.Open
oRead.Position = 2 ' 2?  Why 2?  Don't know, but it works!
oRead.CopyTo oWrite
oWrite.SaveToFile sFile, 2 ' adSaveCreateOverWrite
```

Comment: Mike, I need answers to the following: (A) is the data you're trying to `Write()` being POSTed from a form with the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute?  (B) Are you sure the data in `Request.TotalBytes` belongs strictly to your binary's? (C) Please tell me what the HTTP 500 error debug text is.

Comment: Robert, thank you for replying.  The data is being POSTed (it is in HTTP body) and when I initially asked the question it was just a binary file (a JEPG in fact).  However I solved the problem by looking at the ASP code in the freeaspupload.asp component and using the techniques I found there.  I don't have enough characters left in this reply to post the code I am now using (much more complicated that that I originally posted!), but I will try to put it in a follow-up.  In fact I am now dealing (due to requirements from the other end) with that JPEG data wrapped in multipart/mime boundaries.

Comment: OK, not in a follow-on comment, but appended to my original post.  Note: sFile gets populated with the required filepath elsewhere.